# UIActionSheet Invalid parameter not satisfying: view != nil

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiactionsheet

I'm getting this error after popping some view controllers on a navigation stack, and at the end I get to ask a question through an action sheet. I'm getting the error parameter not satisfying `view != nil`, which drives me crazy because it-so facto is not a `nil` value when I check before calling the action sheet.

```
   if (self.view != nil) {
            NSLog(@"view is not nil");
        }
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"destructive" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very likely that the view you are attempting to display the UIActionSheet in is not attached to the window yet. Try calling showInView after the view is attached to a window. Assuming the above code is in view controller implementation, try calling it in viewDidLoad instead of loadView.

Answer (score 1):

I had to to a [self performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:1.] After each pop, I'm guessing it has to do something with the state of the view. In needs to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

**showInView** was giving me **Invalid parameter not satisfying: view != nil** exception too.. so i tried `[self.view addSubview action sheet];`

showInView should be called after viewDidLoad so if add  [actionSheet showInView:self.view]; in viewDidAppear , it won't crash..

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred in my unit tests in Xcode 4.6.2 when it hit a line that should present a UIActionSheet.  It did not occur in older versions of Xcode.  I think it is because of a similar issue - there is no view to present to during unit testing.

I worked around it by writing my test to modify the underlying data and then test it, rather than present an action sheet and then select a button, and submitted a bug report to Apple.