# iPad with IOS 5.1 - Strange Crash Reports

Tags: iphone, crash, ios5.1

I'm getting quite a few crash reports from users of my App that look like this:

```
Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
    reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: view != nil'

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x36fb8848 0x36fa8000 + 67656 
1   CoreFoundation                      0x33d1d957 0x33c64000 + 760151
2   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3280f345 0x32806000 + 37701
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x3080e3c5 0x3080a000 + 17349
4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x3080e451 0x3080a000 + 17489 
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x3080f825 0x3080a000 + 22565
6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3280f2a9 0x32806000 + 37545
7   CoreFoundation                      0x33c7350d 0x33c64000 + 62733
8   CoreFoundation                      0x33c7336d 0x33c64000 + 62317
9   GraphicsServices                    0x331f1439 0x331ed000 + 17465
10  UIKit                               0x35968e7d 0x35937000 + 204413
11  MyApp                               0x0000379f 0x1000 + 10143
```

The only line that refers to my App is the last one. When I symbolicate it, it ends up at the following line in main.m:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

This really doesn't give me a lot of room to investigate. From the call stack it seems that even the App delegate hasn't been called yet, not to mention other view controllers, so I can't figure out which view the assertion refers to and why it's nil.

The only thing in common for these reports is that they all come from iPads with IOS 5.1. There are no such crash reports from iPads running older versions or for iPhones/iPods.

I couldn't reproduce the crash on our test device, since I don't know what the user did before the crash.

Anyone faced this issue and has a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere you declared a var called "view". That var seems to be nil, when being used. Meaning it was not initiated correctly. Try to add nullchecks at all these points where you allocate *view. If this doesnt help, you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272734/uiactionsheet-invalid-parameter-not-satisfying-view-nil).

Comment: The variable called "view" is not in my code (in fact I don't have any). The assert comes from a system call, not from my code. In any case, f I did have an assert in my code, I should have seen it in the call stack.